# Generating a discrete random subwindow from a given window

Tags: algorithm, random, probability

I'm working on an image processing application, and I have the problem that I'd like to generate a random subwindow from a given window. For instance, given a 5x5 (pixel) window, I would like to generate a subwindow in a given location in x,y with a given width and height. Currently, it's OK to assume that the width and height of the subwindow will always be equal to each other. The original window, however, does not have this constraint.

Currently, I'm just generating a random width/height for the subwindow that I know fits inside of the original window. Then I generate a valid x,y coordinate that allows that subwindow to fit within the original window. The problem with the current approach is that it doesn't respect the fact that *smaller windows are much more plentiful and are therefore more likely to occur*. By choosing a random dimension for the subwindow width/height, I'm assuming that their distribution in terms of width and height is uniform, when in fact it is not.

For instance, imagine we are given a 5x5 window. There are 25 possible 1x1 subwindows, 16 possible 2x2 windows, 9 possible 3x3 windows, 4 possible 4x4 windows, and 1 possible 5x5 window. Thus, I should choose a 1x1 window with a probability of about 0.45 (25/(25+16+9+4+1), a 2x2 window with a probability of about 0.29, etc.

I'm not sure how to quickly generate such allowable subwindows from the correct distribution without brute force evaluating all possible windows and then simply choosing one from the list, but I'm fairly sure there's a smarter approach to doing this, I just don't know where to begin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an *n∙n* window, there are *(n-m+1)²* sub-windows of size *m∙m*.

In general, for an *x∙y* window, there are *(x-m+1)(y-m+1)* sub-windows of size *m∙m*.

Suggested algorithm:

- For each *m*, calculate the number of sub-windows; build an array of these values.
- Sum the values in the array, and generate a uniformly-distributed integer in this range
- Map this integer into the relevant sub-window size (using value-map or range-map)

**Edit:**

Actually you can do better.

- There is 1 sub-window with width x, 2 sub-windows with width *(x-1), ... , x* sub-windows with width *(x-(x-1))*. In total, there are *(1+2+3+...+x)= x(x+1)/2* possible options for width/horizontal-position.
- Generate a uniformly-distributed integer *r* in the range *[1, x(x+1)/2]*.
- Determine the width using the following formula: *w= x-floor( sqrt(2r-1.75)-0.5 )*

Same for the height.

Comment: Yeah, this is approximately what I was thinking too. It *does* require you to do some (fairly quick) calculations across each possible window size, but I'm thinking it's definitely a quicker way to get the "right" answer. I was hoping for something approaching a closed-form solution, but I'll probably go with this.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to put this here even though it isn't quite right because my simulation shows that it is close-ish and perhaps we can work out what the flaw is. if it can't be fixed I will delete it:

```
1) Generate an Px discretely uninform on 1 to X
2) Generate a Py discretely uniform on 1 to Y
3) let Rx = X - Px + 1, let Ry = Y - Py + 1
4) Let A = Rx * Ry - the remaining area we can fill
5) Generate S discretely uniform on 1:min(Rx,Ry)


(Px,Py), (Px+S,Py),(Px,Py+S),(Px+S,Py+S) would define the coordinates of the region
```

Basically I just select the top left corner of the subregion and then randomly select an allowbale square subregion size given that my subregion starts at Rx, Ry position.  The distribution of subregion size has the right diminishing shape, but it is too steep (100,000 iterations of 5x5):

```
1       2       3       4       5
0.60427 0.24523 0.10356 0.03875 0.00819
```

Comment: I think the issue is that if you choose (Px,Py) such that they're close to the top left, then you have the same problem as I did originally: you're going to have a lot of "big windows" to choose from. If you happen to choose (Px,Py) close to the bottom right, then you are much more likely to select smaller windows. Interesting approach, but I don't think it's "correct".

Comment: And don't delete it! I think it's good to leave these things around for other people to look at. Thanks for giving it a shot!

Comment: The things is that I actually wind up with the opposite problem - too many small regions. 60% of my subregions wind-up being size 1 vs 45% proposed distribution.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I did that backwards in my head... hmm... rethink required.

Comment: How about this: we know that "top lefts" are not evenly distributed in the image. For instance, for the largest possible window, the only possible top left value can be (0,0). "Top lefts" are weighted heavily towards *having* to be in the top left of the image in order for the window to fit. What happens if you adjust your algorithm so that it selects the "centre" of the window, and then tries to find a window size from there?

Comment: I think my idea generally doesn't work because it uniformly selects the rows and columns to start in but if you analyze the set of possible (row,column,size) triplets, the rows and columns are not uniform.  I think the only way to make this idea workable is to iterate over the pixels like this generating all the legal triplets and forming an empirical distrubution function for them, then using that as selection function via inverse transform algorithm